# Why does my function return multiple values without values keyword in lisp

Tags: function, return, lisp, common-lisp

I would like to ask why does my function not require to use the values function in order to output a nested list?

```
(defun p2 (l)
(cond
 ((null l) nil)
 ((listp (car l)) ( values (p2 (car l)) (p2 (cdr l))) )
 (t (princ (car l)) (princ " ") (p2 (cdr l)))
 ))
```

I mean doesn't the `cond` construct return 1 value or take 1 action if the condition is true?
And why does this work?

Comment: printing values has nothing to do with returning values. `p2` returns one or two `nil` and that is it. `princ` prints regardsless of return.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(defun p2 (l)
  (cond
    ((null l) ; condition
     nil)     ; body
    ((listp (car l))         ; condition
     (values (p2 (car l))    ; \
             (p2 (cdr l))))  ; /` body
    (t                ; condition
     (princ (car l))  ; \
     (princ " ")      ;  > body
     (p2 (cdr l)))))  ; /
```

This `cond` form has three clauses.  Each clause is a list where the first element is a condition and the rest is a body.  `Cond` looks at each clause in turn until it finds one where the condition is true.  It then executes the body of that clause in an *implicit `progn`*.  `Progn` returns all the values returned by the last form of its body.  `Cond` returns all the values returned by the matching clause.  A function returns all the values returned by its body (which is another implicit `progn`).

As to the “why”: it is defined in this (quite sensible) manner in the standard, and the implementations implement it this way.